# gnome-terminal instance with its own name and Alt+Tab entry

Tags: unity, gnome, window-management

Say I have 3 terminal windows open: 1) With `vim` running, 2) with `top` running, and 3) with nothing running.

Now, if I `Alt+Tab` through my windows, they are all 3 instances of `gnome-terminal`, thus they are grouped together. Is there a way to start the `vim` terminal that will make it stand out for itself, as a separate type of application with its own name in the `Alt+Tab` menu? Ideally also with a custom icon, but that's not a deal breaker for me.

Given the example, it's natural to suggest to use `gvim`, but that's just because `vim` is used in the example. This could also be for the `top` terminal or anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of ubuntu 16.10 i managed to have separate entry for gnome-terminal with

```
 gnome-terminal --class=MC -e mc
```

That starts midnight commander within separate entry of Alt-tab.